# Writing UIImageView name dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios

in the `if` statement below how could i make piece1's name be dynamic so that it checks for other pieces also which are piece1, piece2, ...piece5.

I would have to make it look like something like [@"piece%d",i]  I'm just not sure what the correct way of writing this would be since i'm just starting with iOS.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([piece1 frame], location)){
        piece1.center = location;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    // Create a selector to get the piece
    NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"piece%d", i];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
    UIView *peice = [self performSelector:selector];

    // Now do your test
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([piece frame], location)){
        piece1.center = location;  
    }
}
```

The key bits are `NSSelectorFromString` to turn a string into a selector and `performSelector:` to get the object matching it.

Answer (score 0):

First add tags to your imageView when initializing them
then change your code to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

 UIImageView *piece = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] ;

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([piece frame], location)){
        piece.center = location;  
    }
}
```

make sure your tag matches the value that will be in the loop i values.

Comment: You might want to tweak that a bit - your first tag would be `0`, the default tag for all untagged views. Try `viewWithTag:i+100` and tag your pieces 100, 101, 102 ... ;)